# How to work with c# datatable in jquery ajax in asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webforms

Guys i want to send a datatable from c# to jquery Ajax. if i send string it works properly and if i send datatable it gives the output error below i have posted!

[image]

```
[WebMethod]
            public static DataTable getGuestByGuestIDFront(string guest_id)
            {

                DataTable dt621 = BAL.getGuestByGuestID(guest_id);
                return dt621;
            }
```

Jquery

```
  < script type = "text/javascript" >

 function guest_search() {
     //      debugger;
     var guest_id = $('#guest_id').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'Walkin6.aspx/getGuestByGuestIDFront',
         type: "POST",
         data: "{'guest_id':" + guest_id + "}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             debugger;
             // TabItem2_click();
             console.log(data.d);
             //   alert("Booking ID " + data.d);
             // $("#message").html((data.d));

             //   $(this).prop("disabled", true);

         },
         error: function (result) {
             console.log('Failed' + result.responseText);
         }

     });
 } < /script>
```

This is the output!

> Failed{"Message":"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type \u0027System.Reflection.RuntimeModule\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

is there anyway to work with c# datatable in jquery ajax!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c# code

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static string getGuestByGuestIDFront(string guest_id)
        {
            DataTable dt = BAL.getGuestByGuestID(guest_id);

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            string json = js.Serialize(rows);
            return json;
        }
```

javascript code for success:

```
 success: function (serverdata) {

    var tableData = $.parseJSON(serverdata.d);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(int id)
{
   DataTable dt621 = BAL.getGuestByGuestID(guest_id);

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt621);
}
```

and then in success call of ajax

```
 success: function (data) {

    var tableData = $.parseJSON(data.d);//if you want your data in json
  }
```

Comment: Excellent pointing out JsonConvert.SerializeObject(). However, if third party controls/widgets are used on the client side, $.parseJSON might not be needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

The error says there are circular references. If you know they actually do not exist serialize the object with [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) as the response to AJAX call or create simpler DTO. I had similar problem with default serializer from .net framework - it couldn't serialize an object because of C.R. which actually weren't there! Shifting to Json.NET fixed the problem for me.